# Hashing passwords using bcrypt without a database

Tags: api, express, crud, bcrypt

I created an endpoint to register new users, `/register`.

Since I'm not using a database, I'm updating an array by pushing the new user into it, and then writing this new array into a `json` file using `fs.writeJSONFile()`.

Below is the code for registering a new user:

```js
router.post("/register", m.checkFieldsPost, async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const id = { id: helper.getNewId(users) };

  try {
    const user = await helper.findUser(users, email);
    console.log(`user is ${user}`);
    if (user)
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "That user already exists!",
      });
    // Generate salt
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

    // Hash password
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = {
      ...id,
      password: hashedPassword,
      email,
    };

    await users.push(newUser);
    await helper.writeJSONFile(filename, users);

    return res.status(201).json({
      message: `New user was created`,
      user: newUser,
      originalPassword: password,
      hashedPassword,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    // res.status(500).json({ message: "Mesasge from the catch block" });
  }
});
```

The problem seems to be in my function that looks for a user in the database:

```js
function findUser(array, email) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const row = array.find((r) => r.email == email);
    if (!row) {
      reject({
        message: "User not found",
      });
      reject(null);
    }
    resolve(row);
  });
};
```

I'm trying to register a new user and I first check if the email already exists in the `json` file using the function above:

```js
const user = await helper.findUser(users, email);
```

However, it seems that if the user is not found, the function call ends and I'm sending back a status code to the client. Is there a problem in the way I'm rejecting the promise? How could I return `null` from a promise rejection?

Comment: How many users do you expect to register and how bad would it be if you lost the entire user list file? This can fall apart quickly and in unexpected ways.

Comment: Yeah, this is more for a school exercise as opposed to a full-fledged application. I'm not using this app for real purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Rejecting a promise marks it as rejected / failed. The `await` keyword will then *throw* whatever you passed to `reject(...)`. So your code aborts with an exception when the user is not found. You should put a try/catch around your `await helper.findUser(...)` call. Alternatively, call `resolve(null)` if you want the await to return null instead of throwing.

This also means you shouldn't call `reject` twice, or worse, call both `reject` and `resolve` for the same promise as your code currently does. Calling one of those functions is not equivalent to a return, the function still has to return cleanly.

Comment: Wouldn't putting a `try/catch` block around the `await helper.findUser(...)` result in the same outcome? If the user is not found, then the `catch` block would execute and the rest of the code wouldn't be called.

Comment: That's right but the catch block could set ```user``` to null. I've edited my answer though to include a way to do it without the try/catch - just don't use ```reject```.